# The responsive site doesn't work online, but will work when save and open it on local computer. Why?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsiveness

first time asking here, so hope I'm in the right place.

Below is a site I am working on:
http://iprotion.com/

I just built and tested a mobile friendly theme for it, but I discovered the 'responsive' does not work properly.

When you re-size the browser smaller (as mobile view) while opening that page: http://iprotion.com/ it doesn't work at all. The left sidebar is still in the same spot instead of relocate into above the main content of page. But, it's really weird, if you save this page on local computer and open the saved one by the same browser, resize browser, the responsive will work correctly.

The code of the saved one should be the same with the "online" one, right? Why doesn't the responsive of online one work?

Any ideas and helps would be hugely appreciated! 
Thanks.
Simon.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Firefox 39 and Android 4. What browser are you working with? Do you just mean that the input fields are still on the left side at a resolution of 480×320px (landscape mode)? Just adjust the `@media` query then.

Comment: Oh, weird ! 
Using full address with "www" : http://www.iprotion.com   will work perfectly !

Comment: I don’t see any difference in the `www` version and the one without it, either.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked it in Chrome, Firefox, IE, chrome's mobile test feature

-- it works as you describe it should in all three.

So the first thing to try:

Clear your browser cache and restart your browser and check again

Often when testing a website locally this isn't an issue, but when putting a site up live, it can be.

After making changes to a page or page layout, the previous version can stay stuck in your browser cache for sometime.

Comment: I did clear browsers. But still ....
Now it only works if I use full address with "www" :  www.iprotion.com  
Thinking about use .htaccess to re-direct non-www to www url.

Comment: Interesting. I just checked again and it's no longer working for the non www. The only thing I notice right off is that you don't have viewports/screen types declared for your stylesheets, but that shouldn't make the difference between www and non-www.

Comment: Ah, I've fixed the code a bit at that time, that's why you didn't see those viewports. The site should work well now. I added .htaccess to redirect non www to www. Don't know exactly why the non-www doesn't work thought ^_^ Anyway, thanks guys for quick replies.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've added the responsive media queries to the stylesheet that is in the online version of your site? I see that the left sidebar and the main-content area have `coffee-span-3` and `coffee-span-9` classes respectively. So. there's no way for them to re-align the mobile browser?